# Accumulation point of a sequence and a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

By the definitions, these two can be different. E.g. $(-1)^n$ and  $\{-1,1\}$, where $1$ is an accumulation point for the sequence but not for the set. Then it becomes a bit messy.

Is there any way to define so that we only have one definition contain both of the two cases? Probably, by product topology?

Comment: What is your definition of accumulation point of a set? The same as what we'd normally call limit point ? Or $\omega$-limit point? Or point of total accumulation?

Comment: You'd always have to distinguish between such points for sets (which have no direction) and nets/sequences (which essentially have a directedness to them). They're quite different objects, a sequence is not just the set of its values.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it using [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). We can define accumulation points analogously to sets: A point is an accumulation point of the multiset if, for every open interval containing the point, the sum of the multiplicities of the points in the multiset contained in the interval is infinite.